# My user can't SFTP to a dir even though it's a member of the group that has write permissions to it

Tags: permissions, vsftpd, sftp

I've asked this before and I realize others have as well but I'm still struggling and hoping someone out there has the missing piece of info that will help me get this working.  I've read through all of the posts I can find that are relevant but it seems like I'm already doing all of the suggestions.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I'm running apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04. I have a group of directories (and the files within) that are owned by the `www-data` user. The `www-data` group has write permissions on the directories and files that I'm trying to write to.

`testuser` is a member of the `www-data` group. I get a permissions error when I try to sftp into any of these directories as `testuser`.

If I change ownership of these dirs & files to `testuser`, then I can ftp into them.

How should the permissions be set so that a group member can ftp into the directory and write to it?  I'd like to create a guest ftp account and add that to the group as well but I need to get it working for `testuser` first.

I added myself to `www-data` `/etc/groups` manually. I also restarted apache & when that didn't work, rebooted from the command line. What am I missing?

`write_enable=YES` in my `vsftpd.conf`
`chroot_local_user` is commented out.  No chroot'ing is happening.

Comment: You say you get a "permissions error", can you show the exact error message? this can give a clue as to what's wrong. Also, note that despite the name, vsftpd is *NOT* an SFTP server, it's a plain old FTP protocol server. SFTP is usually handled by the ssh daemon. So any config changes you do in vsftpd will not affect SFTP transfers. Just to double check, it would be good if you told us which SFTP client you're using.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize that vsftp didn't do sftp by default.  I'm using WinSCP to SFTP to my server.  I can do it if testuser owns the directory and files but not if www-data owns it, testuser belongs to the www-data group, and that group has write permissions.  The actual error says "Upload of file was successful, but error occurred while setting the permissions and/or timestamp.  If the problem persists, turn on 'Ignore permission errors' option."  Followed by "Permission denied. Error code 3  Error message from server: Permission denied  Request code: 9"

Comment: Do the files actually upload or are they not present? Also, can you log into a terminal on the server, change to the directory where you want to write, and do `ls -la`, then paste the output in your question, so we can see owners and permissions, and give more advice? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me to pinpoint this.  The file IS actually uploading now.  And the permissions are maintained.  But the ownership (both owner and group) changes from www-data:www-data to testuser:testuser when I upload.  Is there any way to preserve ownership?

Comment: The file will be owned by whoever uploaded the file. You may want to check winscp's options for ownership and permission preservation.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you for your help!  It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: @roadmr: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 0):

Note that despite the name, vsftpd is NOT an SFTP server, it's a plain old FTP protocol server. SFTP is usually handled by the ssh daemon. So any config changes you do in vsftpd will not affect SFTP transfers.

The file will be owned by whoever uploaded the file. You may want to check your SFTP client's options for ownership and permission preservation (WinSCP in your case).

(btw I'm just reformatting the comments as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting the target user group as primary one for ftp user helped.

```
sudo usermod -g <group> <ftp_user>
```